# I cant use a cell value from one sheet to another in google spreadsheet using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Am trying to set formula for a cell in goole spreadsheet using apps script....

Everything going fine until am working in same work sheet, but i have tried to update a cell using another worksheet from the same spreadsheet as follows,

```
sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1).setValue("=Ref!A15");
```

but it shows `error:Unknown range name Ref!A15`

i dont know what am missing here, can anyone please help me to solve this issue...

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because it is trying to find a named range and failing. Instead, use: `sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1).setFormula("=Ref!A15");` to set a formula for a cell.